# What "Data" should be inserted into the argument field of the "createrawtransaction" rpc command

Tags: bitcoin-cli, coinbase-transaction, createrawtransaction

[This](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/createrawtransaction.html) resource states that ["data": "hex",(string, required) A key-value pair. The key must be "data", the value is hex-encoded data](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/createrawtransaction.html#:%7E:text=%22data%22%3A%20%22hex%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(string%2C%20required)%20A%20key%2Dvalue%20pair.%20The%20key%20must%20be%20%22data%22%2C%20the%20value%20is%20hex%2Dencoded%20data).

---

### Questions

1. It says that the field is **"required"** but what exactly should that **`data`** be ??
2. If the **`data`** isn't provided does that invalidate the coinbase transaction (even when block height is encoded into scriptSig)?

I asked the question [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/111184/127251) but an answer wasn't provided. So I decided to make it a stand-alone question.

---

### Goal

1. To confirm what **`data`** should be inserted within [this data field](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/createrawtransaction.html#:%7E:text=%22data%22%3A%20%22hex%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(string%2C%20required)%20A%20key%2Dvalue%20pair.%20The%20key%20must%20be%20%22data%22%2C%20the%20value%20is%20hex%2Dencoded%20data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data field is only for when you want to create data-carrying transactions (ones with an OP_RETURN). This is generally not needed in normal transactions (and its usage there is somewhat controversial even). For coinbase transactions, you do need an OP_RETURN output with the witness commitment as specified in BIP141, if you want to include segwit transactions in your block.

However, you shouldn't use `createrawtransaction` and related RPCs for constructing coinbase transactions, as they will miss the necessary scriptSig contents. Even if you could, it would most likely be so slow as to be useless (a modern miner like an AntMiner S17 needs 13000 coinbases per second). Thus, the miner firmware constructs them using hardcoded logic.

The field is marked as required in the RPC documentation *for such outputs*. If you don't want a data-carrying output, the object simply wouldn't exist.

Comment: So the "data" needed is the string "OP_RETURN"?

Comment: No, the data is whatever you want it to be, and in your case, you don't want it at all. If used, `createrawtransaction` uses an OP_RETURN-based scriptPubKey to encode it in the transaction. But again, this is completely unrelated to anything you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Pieter....... I wish you'd always be online to help me out.....Cheers

Comment: is there a function similar to `createrawtransaction` that allows you to pass a specific scriptsig? I'm dealing with this because I don't know how to encode the transaction in hex without using `createrawtransaction`